# SSRS- repeating Tablix -Total field

Tags: reporting-services

I have a RDLC which the tablix is repeating based on a group. But I can't verify how this is been set up.

But the total of the group is not correct, instead getting the over all total

Say Ex:

```
    Dataset is as follows with 2 records
   1 10 Sec01
   1 11 sec02

Sec01
 1.    1    10   10
           Total 21

Sec02
1.      1    10   11
             Total 21
```

Total of section 01 & 02 is 10 & 11 but it is showing overall total

In the expression It is Sum(Field,"Dataset1") - it is obviously calculating the total of the field in dataset. I need to set this to group level.

I can't get into the group details... Tried looking in to xml view but no luck either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aggregation happens automatically, it is only when you need to change that behaviour that you have to add a scope. Just use:

```
=Sum(Fields!MyField.Value)
```

and it will sum at the scope relevant to where it is - the group level for groups or the entire table for footers.

If you add a scope, for example `=Sum(Fields!MyField.Value, "Dataset1")` then it will do aggregation at that level (in this case, the entire dataset), which is why it is giving the entire dataset's total.